# Running PhantomJS Selenium Web Driver on local IIS stays on about:blank

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm having a very frustrating issue with the Selenium PhantomJS driver in my UI tests in that all the other drivers work as expected but Phantom refuses to navigate anywhere when the address is localhost. Phantom works as expected when using an external URL.

PhantomJS 1.9.7, Selenium Web Driver 2.42.0, IIS 7.5

My very simple test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class AcceptanceTests
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [Test]
    public void HomePageChrome() // works
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/MySite");

        Assert.AreEqual("My Project Name", driver.Title);
    }

    [Test]
    public void HomePagePhantom() // does not work
    {
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/MySite");

        Debug.WriteLine(driver.Url); // about:blank

        Assert.AreEqual("My Project Name", driver.Title);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ExternalPagePhantom() // works
    {
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");

        Assert.AreEqual("Google", driver.Title);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        if (driver != null)
        {
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I've tried adding wait statements after driver.Navigate()... to no avail (either an explicit wait or waiting for a class or id to be found).

What am I missing here? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, in one of my other apps the exact same setup works though. I've come across threads suggesting setting the argument --ignore-ssl-errors=true but Selenium allows to set IgnoreSslErrors on the DriverService and I've already set this and the issue is still present...

Comment: From what I can see is it might be because of URL format. The URL I'm trying to navigate to has a # after a query string e.g. testpage.html?# when I take away ?# it works!

Comment: I've seen solutions similar to yours but no go on our end for any of them. Ended up using the default Firefox driver but we want to move to Phantom for the performance gains. Very frustrating!

Comment: Sorry I did see that PhantomJS does navigate to the page but I think the page I'm loading loads content with Ajax using anchor elements, so passing the #tab-reviews in the URL should make content load. This works with ChromeDriver too but not with PhantomJS, I did a webwait on an element that's expected to load and with Phantom it just never loads. Think I'm going the same route as you.